# Working with date ranges in PostgreSQL to define active sites in a period of time (years)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I am working with a PostgreSQL database of archaeological sites that stores their year of foundation (`start_date`) and the year where they were abandoned (`end_date`) as date fields. These years can be Before the Common Era (BCE) or Common Era (CE) and they range between BCE 900 to nowadays, since some of the sites were abandoned in the past, but many of them are still inhabited. Here is [a snapshot of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cmUJ.png) I am using to give you a better idea of what I am dealing with.

My aim is to build a query to define the sites that were occupied between two specific years (BCE 27 and CE 235) using this dataset. This [is a graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XCOd.jpg) showing this objective,  which should result in the selection of Sites A, B, C and D, but not E. For this purpose, I have tried several solutions:

```
select site_id, name, type, start_date, end_date 
from site_date 
where start_date between '0027-01-01 BC' and '0235-01-01';
```

...shows sites starting between these two years, but not those active between them.

```
select site_id, name, type, start_date, end_date 
from site_date 
where end_date >= '0235-01-01';
```

...shows sites ending before CE 235.

...as well as variations of the previous.

I realized that these applications were actually defining the sites whose start and end dates fall within BCE 27 and CE 235, but not those (still active in this period) whose foundation was before the start date and whose abandonment was after the end date. How to solve this issue?

Comment: [mre] [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)

Comment: @Amirhossein Please when editing remove  all "fluff" : [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097) (Every question post implicitly asks "Any help".) That includes social & meta commentary. See my edits. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72521490/revisions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is anything that has a `start_date <='0235-01-01' AND end_date >='0027-01-01 BC'`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution! It took me a while to get it, but I know understand the logic  of your answer and how I was missing the point in my previous attempts (it's been a long two days...).

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code...

Where (start_date <= 27BCE and end_date >= 27BCE)
OR
(start_date between 27BCE and 235CE)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was yet another way to solve the issue I had.

Answer (score 0):

AS per graphic shown, I understood sample data  [is here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0024494209eea90af0d3a4af8e8a988f), you wanted A, B, C and D but not E, these site were having end date > '0027-01-01 BC'
and these site exists between BCE 27 and CE 235,

```
select * from site_date 
where end_date > '0027-01-01 BC'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for this answer... and for the tool for testing sql. I didn't know it and I see myself using it from now on :)

Answer (score 0):

Postgres fully understands BCE dates and therefore all date functions work properly with them. Unfortunately some instances do not *display* them correctly and will *display* '2021-01-01 BC' and '2021-01-01' exactly the same. You may actually need to use `to_char(date_column, 'FMyyyy-mm-dd bc')` to get the proper display.  

The following converts your date sets (start_date, end_date) and the desired date start, end dates into a [daterange](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN) then uses the [overlaps](https://%20https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html) operator (&&) to determine where any part of the (start_date, end_date) falls within the specified range. (See [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1347e09e8b727f90278196e53633383b). It also adds a row with a `null` end date to show how still inhabited can work.)

```
with target_range(founded_date,abandoned_date) as  
     ( values (date '0027-01-01 BC', date '0235-01-01') )
select s.* 
  from sites         s 
  join target_range  tr
    on (  daterange(s.start_date, s.end_date, '[]')  && 
          daterange(tr.founded_date,tr.abandoned_date, '[]')
       ) ;
```

Additional Ref: [make_date](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) function

Comment: thank you so much for this comment: I wasn't aware of this issue and you have (for sure) helped me avoid headaches in the near future.